# Spring Boot doesn't load application.yml config or?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a simple main app:

```
// Application.java
package com.my.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.my")
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Just a class:

```
// TestClass.java
package com.my.application;

public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {

    }
}
```

With config:

```
//ApplicationConfiguration
package com.my.configuration;

import com.my.application.TestClass;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean TestClass getTestClass()
    {
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("test"));

        return new TestClass();
    }
}
```

this is my pom file:

```
// pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the application.yml file is just:

```
// src/main/resources/application.yml

test: 123
```

Property "test" always = null.
What I was wrong?
Tried with @Value, @ConfigurationProperties, 
@EnableConfigurationProperties,
@PropertySource("classpath:src/main/resources/application.yml") annotations, 
without the snakeyaml library,
with another spring-boot versions,
but result always the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to do with Maven - `application.properties` is not part of the build when you're using `<packaging>pom</packaging>` in your pom file - hence when you start the Application, the file is not there to be read.

Remove `<packaging>pom</packaging>` from your pom and you should be good to go.

Comment: my app is modular, I need my parent packaging to be pom. Is there a way to use module yaml, since my module packaging is jar?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue. Tried lot of things, but it nothing worked.

In the end, when I added below dependency in pom, my application is able to read `application.yml` file.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

try adding dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor`